# How to execute a task between a certain time period regardless of the Date

Tags: java

I have a Thread in my application which runs continuously till the application is stopped .

I want to change its behavior to run only during the time period from **9 AM to 6 PM** regardless of the  Date

As per the suggestion below , i have done this
please let me know if this has got any negative impact .

```
package com;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class ContinousThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // is automatically initialized to
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            boolean run = hour >= 9 && hour < 18;
            if (run) {
                doSomething();
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
            }
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // actual task
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ContinousThread ct = new ContinousThread();
        ct.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use Joda Time instead, where you could parse to a LocalTime instead of a Date. That'll make things much simpler. Oh, and you mean HH rather than hh.

Comment: This is for once perfectly easy to solve with the JDK classes. No need for Joda here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have done this please let me know if this has got any negative
>   impact

There is.

```
boolean run = hour >= 9 && hour < 18;
if (run) {
    doSomething();
} else {
    System.out.println("No");
}
```

When `run` is `false` you have a ["busy loop"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). This will make the cpu busy, very busy. And also print *tons* of `No` on console.

One approach is to put a `sleep` in the `else` block. You can probably sleep for a long time at `18:00`, compute how far you are from the next `9:00` and sleep for that much (or a little less)

Comment: i will remove the else condition consistng of sys out . this is for understanding only .

Comment: You need to replace it with a `sleep`, not just remove it.

Comment: if i put the Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); inside while true will it have performance issue

Comment: Yes, it will. Step through the code in debugger, it should be pretty apparent. If you want to discuss further, we can chat.

Comment: thanks a lot , then is there any other way i can achive this requirement without Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  , i guess i should use new Date() , but new java.util.Date().getHours() is depricated know

Comment: No, that's not necessary. Please join http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39295/stackoverflow-com-questions-19386293

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39296/discussion-between-miserable-variable-and-preethi-jain)

Comment: In chat you mentioned that `doSomething` will queue a task with an `Executor`. This will result in lot of executions of `doSomething` which is not a good thing. Since the task has to write to db, you will likely have huge queues with the db write lagging behind.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Calendars get(field) method to get the hour:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // is automatically initialized to current date/time
 int hour = c.getField(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 boolean run = hour >= 9 && hour < 18;
```

Comment: Thanks , As per the suggestion  , i have modified the question above ,please  let me know if this has got any negative impact .

Comment: @PreethiJain Your code now will continuously poll the time and print "No" to the console or you would continously call doSomething(). You should put a reasonable delay in loop passes, like check once every minute. Try adding a Thread.sleep(60000) to the loop (or whatever is suitable in your case. You may want to use different sleep periods depending on if the time condition is satisfied or not).

Comment: my concern is that if i put the Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); inside while true will it have performance issue ??

Comment: @PreethiJain I wouldn't expect any performance problems from Calendar.getInstance(), I presume what you actually do in doSomething() will take far more time. But you can easily get the calendar *before* the loop and instead of creating a new instance every time, just use c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()) to update the calendar to the current time.